# Batch not working and I will go with powershell instead

Tags: powershell

I have a machine that reduces pictures brought from Dropbox by several users and then sent to a cloud storage where traffic costs.

the batch file has worked fine in windows 10 task scheduler but it will not function when exported to Windows 11.
I am trying to transform it to Powershell but I get stuck by some features from RoboCopy.

the batch looks like this:

```
set "source=C:\kilde1"

set "destination=C:\kilde2"

Set "resize=C:\kilde3"

Set "move=S:\kilde4"

robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" /mov /E /XD .*

del /s /f /q /a:h "%destination%"

robocopy "%destination%" "%destination%" /S /move

2jpeg.exe -src "%destination%\*.*" -dst "%resize%" -oper Resize size:"1920 1080" -options overwrite:yes -options delsrc:yes

robocopy "%destination%" "%resize%" /mov /E /XD .*

robocopy "%resize%" "%move%" /move /E

del /s /f /q /a:h "%move%"

robocopy "%move%" "%move%" /S /move

exit /b
```

this script leaves the folder structure in source folder though emptying the folders. this helps the emploies to load more pictures correctly. the script also makes some cleanup that I want to preserve to make sure the computer keeps running.
Can anyone help create a Powershell script doing the same?
the 2jpeg.exe is the programe that actually reduces the pictures.
The script shall run several times daily to keep a process running.

I have googled for other people trying some similar things but I have not been able to find any

I tried myself to start in Powershell like this:

```
#Original picture folder
$source = "C:\Kilde1"

#Folder to work with files
$destination = "C:\Kilde2"

#Folder for reducing for 2jpeg - pictures are reducet
$reseize = "C:\Kilde3"

#Folder final store
$move = "S:\Kilde4"

#Move Pictures from Source folder to destination
Get-ChildItem $source | Move-Item -Destination $destination
```

already here first problem - the original folder will be totally empty - the folder structure is also gone.

Comment: Robocopy.exe can still be used in a PowerShell script.

Comment: For calling your `2jpeg.exe` with `$destination` and `$resize` being PS variables you could try running using invocation operation `&` as 
`& '2jpeg.exe' -src "$($destination)\*.*" -dst $resize -oper Resize size:"1920 1080" -options overwrite:yes -options delsrc:yes`

Comment: thank you for your comment but I need to start with moving data from source to destination without destroying folder structure - that is my startup problem. If you think RoboCopy will be fine - OK - I will try - but in the end it shall run as a task in scheduler and the batch do not run.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve folder structure you need to move items recursively.
Try with using -Recurse switch for Get-ChildItem

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination $destination
```

Comment: Sorry but the folder structure in folder c:\Kilde1 disappeared

Comment: I finally got the problem solved so the question wil end here